# Update duplicate records with incremental column

Tags: mysql, sql

-- create

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
  emp_id INTEGER,
  job_code TEXT,
  cnt_check int
);
```

-- insert

```
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0001, 'JC001');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0001, 'JC001');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0002, 'JC002');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0002, 'JC002');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0003, 'JC003');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0004, 'JC004');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0004, 'JC004');
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,job_code) VALUES (0004, 'JC004');
```

**Expected Output**:

```
emp_id  job_code  cnt_check
--------------------------------
0001    JC001       1
0001    JC001       2
0002    JC002       1
0002    JC002       2
0003    JC003       1
0004    JC004       1
0004    JC004       2
0004    JC004       3
```

My try:

```
update employee t1
join 
(
select emp_id ,job_code ,row_number() over(partition by emp_id ,job_code ) rnk
from employee
) t2 
on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id and t1.job_code = t2.job_code 
set t1.cnt_check = t2.rnk;
```

But all records getting updated with value 1.

[Demo link](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yy6x4wf6)

Comment: Something went wrong transcribing to question - create table is for employee and the code is for student..

Comment: @P.Salmon, My bad, just created those names for demo purpose.

Comment: Create a trigger which will generate this AI value using base MyISAM service table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the exact columns in your sample data, we can try:

```sql
SELECT emp_id, job_code,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id) AS cnt_check
FROM employee
ORDER BY 1, 3;
```

Note that I suggest *not* doing this update, as every time your data changes you might have to run the update again.

Comment: But while updating it's getting `1` updated.

Comment: Your update cannot be made to work, as there is no way to distinguish the duplicates.

Comment: change ORDER BY emp_id to ORDER BY job_code and let mysql handle the duplicates https://dbfiddle.uk/jQEM6uFW

Answer (score 1):

You may use generation which uses BEFORE INSERT trigger and additional table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE autoinc_helper (
  emp_id INT,
  cnt_check INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, cnt_check)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER generate_autoinc
BEFORE INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE autoinc INT;
  INSERT INTO autoinc_helper (emp_id) VALUES (NEW.emp_id);
  SET autoinc = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  SET NEW.cnt_check = autoinc;
  DELETE FROM autoinc_helper WHERE emp_id = NEW.emp_id AND cnt_check < autoinc;
END
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Prxer-RN)

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE your_table t
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    uniqueid,
    (@row_number := IF(@prev_value = column1, @row_number + 1, 1)) AS row_number,
    (@prev_value := emp_id) AS emp_id  
  FROM your_table,
    (SELECT @row_number := 0, @prev_value := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY emp_id, uniqueid
) t2 ON t.uniqueid= t2.uniqueid
SET t.cnt_check= t2.row_number;
```