# Auto increment by group mariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, auto-increment

I have this MariaDB table.

```
id   order   name  forum_id
1      1     ....      1
2      2     ....      1
3      3     ....      1
4      1     ....      2
5      2     ....      2
```

where **id** is PK.

**order** is the user given numbers to arrange names

**name** is , well, name of the topic

and **forum_id** is foreign key to another table

in this table order and forum_id is unique together.`UNIQUE('order', 'forum_id')`. which means you can not add another **order=1** into where **forum_id=1**. Becasue this duality already exist.

now my question is how i can make **order** is autoincrement field according to **forum_id**?For instance: when another  **forum_id=1** is added order will get the value of  **4**. and another **forum_id=2** is added order will get number **3**.so my database will look like this

```
id   order   name  forum_id
1      1     ....      1
2      2     ....      1
3      3     ....      1
4      1     ....      2
5      2     ....      2
6      4     ....      1 
7      3     ....      2
```

I saw this question has been asked in different shapes in the past. But most of the asked questions is coming from 10-15 years ago. so i thought maybe this problem got an answer as i use mariaDB 11.

Comment: You could use `row_number() over (partition by forum_id order by id) as order`, so there is no need to store the order as a column.

Comment: You may create your table on MyISAM and use secondary autoincremented column in PK. Alternatively you may use additional table and BEFORE INSERT trigger. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485284/10138734

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT has to fulfill exactly 2 tasks:

- Generate a unique integer value that can be used to efficiently and quickly access a data set.
- reflect the chronological order (without time specification) in which the data sets were generated.

AUTO_INCREMENT should not be used for other logical constructs, particularly those that assume that the auto_increment values ​​represent a series of consecutively numbered values.

Using a composite index with an auto_increment has two serious disadvantages: querying a composite index is slower and the chronological order of the records is no longer available.

To avoid redundancy, ORDER should be a computed column and not stored in the database.
As already suggested in Ahmed's comment, a window function should be used. Since the auto_increment values ​​are unique, it doesn't matter whether RANK, DENSE_RANK or ROW_NUMBER is used.

```
SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY forum_id ORDER BY id) AS `order`,
       name, forum_id FROM yourtable
```