# Composite Primary Key with auto increment in innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have created a table as below with `MYISAM`:

```
CREATE TABLE zzz_test.`table_with_index` (
  `grp_name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  `sub_grp` INT NOT NULL,
  `item_index` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`grp_name`,`sub_grp`,`item_index`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM
```

| grp_name | sub_grp | item_index | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GRP_A | 1 | 1 | .... |
| GRP_A | 1 | 2 | .... |
| GRP_A | 1 | 3 | .... |
| GRP_A | 2 | 1 | .... |
| GRP_A | 2 | 2 | .... |
| GRP_A | 2 | 3 | .... |
| GRP_B | 1 | 1 | .... |
| GRP_B | 1 | 2 | .... |
| GRP_B | 1 | 3 | .... |
| GRP_B | 2 | 1 | .... |
| GRP_B | 2 | 2 | .... |
| GRP_B | 2 | 3 | .... |

I want to know why `INNODB` does not support such configuration?
Also, is there any simple way to have same outcome in `INNODB`?
(I have to insert this table from another with select)

Comment: I want to know why INNODB does not support such configuration?' - best ask mysql dev team

Comment: BTW innodb would be happy if item_index was first node of compound key https://dbfiddle.uk/3M3w94Fc

Comment: But the item_index will always keep increment without reset to 1 for new combination of grp_name-sub_grp

Comment: which field you have from the other select and which must created

Comment: *is there any simple way to have same outcome in INNODB?* Yes. Trigger + additional table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485284/10138734

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75484208/update-duplicate-records-with-incremental-column/75485284#75485284) really help me get it done as follow.

```
CREATE DATABASE zzz_test;
CREATE TABLE zzz_test.`table_raw` (
  `grp_name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  `sub_grp` INT NOT NULL,
  `item` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
INSERT INTO zzz_test.`table_raw` VALUES 
  ('GRP_A',1, 'xxx'),
  ('GRP_A',2, 'yyy'),
  ('GRP_A',1, 'yyy'),
  ('GRP_A',2, 'xxx'),
  ('GRP_B',1, 'xxx'),
  ('GRP_B',1, 'yyy'),
  ('GRP_B',2, 'yyy'),
  ('GRP_B',2, 'xxx')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE zzz_test.`table_with_index` (
  `grp_name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  `sub_grp` INT NOT NULL,
  `item_index` INT NOT NULL,
  `item` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`grp_name`,`sub_grp`,`item_index`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
INSERT INTO zzz_test.`table_with_index`
SELECT grp_name, sub_grp,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY grp_name,sub_grp 
            ORDER BY grp_name,sub_grp,item
       ) AS item_index,
       item
FROM zzz_test.`table_raw`
ORDER BY grp_name,sub_grp,item;
```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM zzz_test.`table_with_index`;
```

| grp_name | sub_grp | item_index | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GRP_A | 1 | 1 | xxx |
| GRP_A | 1 | 2 | yyy |
| GRP_A | 2 | 1 | xxx |
| GRP_A | 2 | 2 | yyy |
| GRP_B | 1 | 1 | xxx |
| GRP_B | 1 | 2 | yyy |
| GRP_B | 2 | 1 | xxx |
| GRP_B | 2 | 2 | yyy |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0kfxPYyC)